# Not callable string object

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, typeerror

```
def power(num,div):
    incre =0 
    while(num%div == 0):
        num = num/div
        incre +=1
    return incre
test_case = int(raw_input())

lim = 0

while lim  < test_case:
    power = (raw_input())
    x = power.split()
    a = int(x[0])
    b = int(x[1])
    lim +=1
print power(a,b)
```

Python  used to work normally until I had this error.

Comment: Which Error? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 9):

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) always returns a string object.  Because of that, this line:

```
power = (raw_input())
```

makes `power` a string.  Furthermore, when this happens, it overrides your function `power`.

When you get to this point:

```
print power(a,b)
```

`power` is a string and you get an error for trying to call it as you would a function.

To fix the problem, either rename the function or the string.  They both can't be named `power`.

Comment: thank you,I made the power function earlier,just copied it,will use import from next time

Comment: The problem arises when you give the two things the same name. Importing will not help, except if the function belongs to some package, in which case, for example, you would call myfunctions.power(a,b). In this case the namespaces are different, and there is no collision.

Comment: @user2688772 Even if you import `power` into your namespace, if you overwrite it with a string you will get the same error.  You need to name the power string something else.